# Designing an Algorithm That Pulls Interesting Facts from a Data Set

Tags: algorithm, random, artificial-intelligence

In the book The Pragmatic Programmer they discuss an algorithm that may be useful for a sports reporter. The algorithm would pull interesting sports facts from a wide data set of baseball statistics, enabling the reporter to discuss on air only the most interesting facts provided.

This is a design I want to employ in a Java project utilizing a SQL database. What would that design look like? As well, if there is a name for this "field of study" please provide it as finding information for such a design is difficult.

Thank you

Comment: This is an incredibly broad question. Pulling interesting facts from a data set sounds like data mining. An interesting book on sports statistics is "Analyzing Baseball Data with R" which even though it targets R should still give you some ideas. You discover rapidly that baseball data is scattered in various sources and requires a nontrivial amount of parsing to get anything like a useable database. ESPN etc. doubtless have proprietary DBs. "Data munging" is sometimes used to describe the problem of getting data into a useable format.

Comment: There is also https://datascience.stackexchange.com/